# Does the Reapers' Silent Killer skill make them undetectable when they destroy objects?

Tags: xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

The Silent Killer ability allows a Reaper to stay indefinitely concealed as long as he/she only fires killing shots.

If a Reaper fires against a destructible target and destroys it, will the reveal chance be 0%?

Comment: It's not an answer to the question, but check out the Remote Start ability. It does this and doubles the range and damage of the explosion.

Comment: Destructible target also means the transmitter relays you have to destroy in some missions, so it's not limited to explosive objects

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I do know that Reapers stay IN stealth "activating" resistance people in a resistance mission, and LEAVE stealth activating a container in a supply mission.  (That last was rather embarrassing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having attempted this just now, shooting at a destructible such as a radio relay, and killing it from shadow with the silent killer perk, will increase your chance to be detected as normal.